# Installing a bookmark icon on a user's mobile phone

Tags: web-applications, mobile, mobile-website

I'm creating a mobile web app and I'm looking for a way to let the user install an icon to their phone that launches the site (much like launching an app) - I think is there is a way to do this but I'm having a hard time finding a tutorial or example of it.

Answer (score 1):

Each platform has their own implementation of this.

For iOS, the user's can "Add to Home Screen" from within Safari.

Refer to the [Apple WebApp](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html) document for details.

For instance, to set the icon, add this to your page:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png"/>
```

You can also set individual icons for different sizes, and also the splash screen.

Comment: I was looking for something where it could be a one-click on the screen somewhere. I did find this which is an automated script of sorts: http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen not great but it's a start (no android support though)

Comment: There is no way to trigger this from your web page. That site you mentioned is useful for drawing attention to the user that you have a page optimized for running as a web app. But the only way to get a web app is for the user to press "Add to Home Screen" manually.

Comment: take look : http://www.olivieralbertini.com/tutorial/create-icon-for-mobile . it's a start. You should find some interesting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One to do so is to build an app.

The application either has an embedded web browser pointing to the site or loads the web browser and tells it to point to your web site

To do this on android see the [documention on webView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)